# Conditional statement fails to initialize sound file

Tags: python, mqtt

I have a python script that listens for incoming mqtt payloads and should play a sound file with Sox `os.system('play --no-show-progress %s --channels 2 synth %s' % (sound1, duration))` depending on the publication from the client, but it doesn't.

Upon further investigation i discovered that when i put the call to initialize the sound file directly under the `on_message` function, the sound file plays. But if i make the statement conditional it fails to do so without giving any error.

Here's my full code.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from subprocess import Popen
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time

duration = 5  # second

sound1 = "/home/pi/auto_response/laser_alert.wav"
sound2 = "/home/pi/auto_response/online.wav"
sound3 = "<path>.mp3"
sound4 = "<path>.mp3"
sound5 = "<path>.mp3"

mqtt_topics = ["laser", "motion", "cam", "temp"] # Change to multiple topics that suits your needs. 
mqtt_broker_ip = "xxx.xxx.x.xx" 
client = mqtt.Client() 

# These functions handle what happens when the MQTT client connects
# to the broker, and what happens then the topic receives a message
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print "Connected!", str(rc)  # rc is the error code returned when connecting to the broker
    for topic in mqtt_topics:
        client.subscribe(topic) # Once the client has connected to the broker, subscribe to the topic
    # This function is called everytime the topic is published to.
    # If you want to check each message, and do something depending on
    # the content, the code to do this should be run in this function   
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):  
        #os.system('aplay -d {} {}'.format(duration_time, response_path)) 
    if msg.payload == "close":
        os.system('play --no-show-progress %s --channels 2 synth %s' % (sound1, duration))
    elif msg.payload == "open":
        os.system('play --no-show-progress %s --channels 2 synth %s' % (sound1, duration))
    elif msg.payload == "on":
        os.system('play --no-show-progress %s --channels 2 synth %s' % (sound3, duration))
    elif msg.payload == "off":
        os.system('play --no-show-progress %s --channels 2 synth %s' % (sound4, duration))
    elif msg.payload == "motion":
        os.system('play --no-show-progress %s --channels 2 synth %s' % (sound5, duration)) 

    print "Topic: ", msg.topic + "\nMessage: " + str(msg.payload) # The message itself is stored in the msg variable and details about who sent it are stored in userdata

# Here, we are telling the client which functions are to be run
# on connecting, and on receiving a message
client.on_connect = on_connect ()
client.on_message = on_message ()

# Once everything has been set up, we can (finally) connect to the broker
# 1883 is the listener port that the MQTT broker is using
client.connect(mqtt_broker_ip, 1883)

# Once we have told the client to connect, let the client object run itself
client.loop_forever()
client.disconnect()
```

Comment: Please fix your code snippet indentation so that it __exactly__ matches your real code.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to fix that. I pasted the whole code and had to manually indent it to make it show as code.

Comment: Edit your post, delete all the code, copy/paste it again, then select the _whole_ code snippet and click the "code" button (the one labeled "{}") in the editor's toolbar. Double check (in the preview) that everything's ok, submit, done.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers done.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: @hardillb Python 2.7.9

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` and `elif` statements condition on `msg.payload` being in

`["close", "open", "on", "off", "motion"]`

Is it possible that `msg.payload` has a different value, and thus never enters any of the conditional stements? Include a final `else` statement to catch these scenarios.

Comment: I'm not sure about payload having a different value but let me try the final else statement.

Comment: I'm seeing some progress after adding `else: 
        os.system('play --no-show-progress %s --channels 2 synth %s' % (sound2, duration))` at the last part of the `on_message` function, the sound file on the else statement was played.  However the if statements still do not work play sound.

Comment: @AllenJakpa the the values for `msg.payload` may not be what you expect...  I of course assume the `os.system` call themselves work as expected. Printing out `msg.payload`, and printing out the command string and the `os.system()` call return value in each if/elif branch should help you find out what's wrong (basic debugging howto, really).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I've tried every option available. is it possible that paho client has a bug causing this issue?